# Classpath jar files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am new to eclipse and I have a general question about referencing external Jar files.

I went to the *buildpath -> configure build path* and added my two jar files that I wanted to reference as parts of an external library but I can seem to make an instance object of the classes in that jar.

And also I tried just copy and pasting the jar files to the extension folder of the standard library too but this also doesn't work.

How can I use the instance objects of the classes included in these jar files?

Comment: do you import the needed classes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you can't make an instance of an Object in the jar? In fact, you said you **can**, but I assume that's a typo. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: so there are classes within the jar file i downloaded that I need to use in my source code. I want to make an object of that class in the jar file in my source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you build path to external JARs you have to `import` the required classes because they do not actually exist inside the same package you are working at.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to add external jars into eclipse follow these steps

Rightclick on project - Select Configure Build Path... and the project properties window will appear showing your build path configurations.

Click Add Variable --Click Configure Variables 
Click New -Type a name for the new variable.--Browse to the directory that contains the JAR for the path.
Click Ok to define the variable.--Click Ok to close the preferences dialog.
Select the variable from the list.--Click Extend..
Select the JAR(s) that you want to add to the classpath.--Select the JAR(s) that you want to add to the classpath.-Click Ok to close the new classpath variable dialog.

Answer (score -1):

If you already added jar file into classpath and if it doesn't work I would try below on command prompt

```
java -classpath example.jar;
```